# Kubernetes ingress rewrite-target and the rewrite regex/capture group (?i)

Tags: regex, nginx, kubernetes

Based on [this guide](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/).

I have created this ingress:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-rewrite-log: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
  name: ing-something
  namespace: samples
spec:
  rules:
  - host: myhost.internal
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: my-app
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /api(/|$)(.*)
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - myhost.internal
    secretName: lets
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - {}
```

When I take a look at the bottom of the generated nginx.config it contains:

```
## start server myhost.internal
server {
    server_name myhost.internal ;
    
    listen 80;
    
    set $proxy_upstream_name "-";
    set $pass_access_scheme $scheme;
    set $pass_server_port $server_port;
    set $best_http_host $http_host;
    set $pass_port $pass_server_port;
    
    listen 443  ssl http2;
    ...
    location ~* "^/api(/|$)(.*)" {
        
        set $namespace      "samples";
        set $ingress_name   "ing-something";
        set $service_name   "my-app";
        set $service_port   "8080";
    set $location_path  "/api(/|${literal_dollar})(.*)";
        
        ...
        

        
        rewrite "(?i)/api(/|$)(.*)" /$2 break;
        proxy_pass http://upstream_balancer;
        
        proxy_redirect                          off;
        
    }
    
    location ~* "^/" {
        
        set $namespace      "";
        set $ingress_name   "";
        set $service_name   "";
        ...
    }
```

I don't understand where this part `(?i)` is coming from in:

```
        rewrite "(?i)/api(/|$)(.*)" /$2 break;
```

and what it means.

Any ideas?

Comment: not 100% sure, but I found this https://www.regular-expressions.info/refmodifiers.html which suggest `(?i)` turns on case insensitivity.

Comment: The path matching [is case-insensitive by default](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#use-regex)

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor Not really sure what to do with it can I click an approve/apply button somewhere? Looks fine!

Comment: Hello @u123. I have post a community wiki answer for better visibility. I will not get any reputation for it but it would be easier for others to find. Feel free to approve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a community wiki answer based on the info from the comments and posted for better visibility. Feel free to expand it.

As already pointed out in the comments, the path matching [is case-insensitive by default](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#use-regex):

> Using the `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex` annotation will
> indicate whether or not the paths defined on an Ingress use regular
> expressions. The default value is `false`.
>
> The following will indicate that regular expression paths are being
> used:
>
> ```
> nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
> ```
>
> The following will indicate that regular expression paths are not
> being used:
>
> ```
> nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "false"
> ```
>
> When this annotation is set to `true`, the case insensitive regular
> expression [location modifier](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) will be enforced on ALL paths for a
> given host regardless of what Ingress they are defined on.
>
> Additionally, if the [`rewrite-target` annotation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#rewrite) is used on any
> Ingress for a given host, then the case insensitive regular expression
> [location modifier](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) will be enforced on ALL paths for a given host
> regardless of what Ingress they are defined on.
>
> Please read about [ingress path matching](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/ingress-path-matching/) before using this
> modifier.

And all the specifics regarding the Mode Modifiers can be found [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refmodifiers.html):

> Mode modifier syntax consists of two elements that differ among regex
> flavors. Parentheses and a question mark are used to add the modifier
> to the regex. Depending on its position in the regex and the regex
> flavor it may affect the whole regex or part of it. If a flavor
> supports at least one modifier syntax, then it will also support one
> or more letters that can be used inside the modifier to toggle
> specific modes. If it doesn’t, “n/a” is indicated for all letters for
> that flavors.

Notice the [Specifying Modes Inside The Regular Expression](https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) for case-insensitivity:

```
(?i)    Turn on case insensitivity. (?i)a matches a and A.
```

Comment: That does not mention the specifics of (?i) from https://www.regular-expressions.info/refmodifiers.html (which was my original question) provided by @Sumit in the first comment.